# How to use Display Template(Search result) to change the dispform.aspx and editform.aspx to a custom one?

Tags: search, search-results, display-template, result-source

I have setup a result source and currently when i do a search it returns some pages with allitem.aspx,disform.aspx and editform.aspx but i want to do the following:-
- Remove the allitems.aspx for this particular list
- Change the disform.aspx?ID=itemID and editform.aspx?ID=itemID to a custom page e.g showNews.aspx(which would look like this showNews.aspx?ID=itemID

Is this possible for just some particular lists and not all lists?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would start by adding a custom display template for the items that converts the result URL to your new page. Since you want to keep the result and only change the destination that would be a good start.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.But any resources to help get that started would be appreciated

Comment: Try this for Display Templates: https://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/

Comment: Thanks Matt would check it out

Comment: If i need to change the OTB search result which specific template should i be modifying? Is it the Control_SearhResults.html?

Comment: I need to change  the displayform.aspx and allitems.aspx to a custom page e.g customdisplay.aspx?ID=1

Comment: Yes, just create new pages.

Comment: Matthew i have the new pages that i want.But as i said which specific control templates do i need to change?

Comment: Create a Result Type rule based on your Content Type (or other attribute that uniquely identifies your content) and specify your Display Template. In your display template add the URL to your custom page.